# x86_64 assembly instructions changed in link stage of GCC

Tags: gcc, assembly, optimization, linker, ld

I'm compiling a program using the sqlite3 libary in Linux(centos7_64). As the user has an old CPU, I set the -march=nehalem flag in GCC (-march=nehalem -mtune=nehalem -m64 -O3). I find I can't limit the assembly instructions to nehalem, some BMI operations still exist in the final binary.

Follow the output step by step, I find the problem comes from the linker (ld).

libsqlite3.a:

```
   632c2:       66 41 83 4f 26 01       orw    $0x1,0x26(%r15)
   632c8:       0f b6 84 24 80 00 00    movzbl 0x80(%rsp),%eax
   632cf:       00
   632d0:       c1 e0 08                shl    $0x8,%eax
   632d3:       89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
   632d5:       0f b6 84 24 81 00 00    movzbl 0x81(%rsp),%eax
   632dc:       00
   632dd:       c1 e0 10                shl    $0x10,%eax
   632e0:       09 d0                   or     %edx,%eax
   632e2:       8d 90 00 fe ff ff       lea    -0x200(%rax),%edx
   632e8:       41 89 47 30             mov    %eax,0x30(%r15)
   632ec:       81 fa 00 fe 00 00       cmp    $0xfe00,%edx
   632f2:       0f 87 d1 05 00 00       ja     638c9 <sqlite3BtreeOpen+0xb29>
   632f8:       8d 50 ff                lea    -0x1(%rax),%edx
   632fb:       85 c2                   test   %eax,%edx
   632fd:       0f 85 c6 05 00 00       jne    638c9 <sqlite3BtreeOpen+0xb29>
```

However, in the final binary:

```
  9499f2:       66 41 83 4f 26 01       orw    $0x1,0x26(%r15)
  9499f8:       0f b6 84 24 80 00 00    movzbl 0x80(%rsp),%eax
  9499ff:       00
  949a00:       0f b6 94 24 81 00 00    movzbl 0x81(%rsp),%edx
  949a07:       00
  949a08:       c1 e0 08                shl    $0x8,%eax
  949a0b:       89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  949a0d:       89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
  949a0f:       c1 e0 10                shl    $0x10,%eax
  949a12:       09 c8                   or     %ecx,%eax
  949a14:       8d 90 00 fe ff ff       lea    -0x200(%rax),%edx
  949a1a:       41 89 47 30             mov    %eax,0x30(%r15)
  949a1e:       81 fa 00 fe 00 00       cmp    $0xfe00,%edx
  949a24:       0f 87 cf 05 00 00       ja     949ff9 <sqlite3BtreeOpen+0xb09>
  949a2a:       c4 e2 78 f3 c8          blsr   %eax,%eax
  949a2f:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  949a31:       0f 85 c2 05 00 00       jne    949ff9 <sqlite3BtreeOpen+0xb09>
```

Notice the last few lines, the linker changed the **lea** to **blsr**, which is unexpected.

Thus, why will this happen. Will the linker (ld) optimize the code further? How to limit the instrutions for the linker to use?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't enable link-time optimization / code-gen with `-flto`?   Normally a good thing to allow cross-file inlining, but you need to set the right arch and optimization options for that, too.  Clearly you have something other than baseline set for whatever generated the final code.  (Or you linked some different object files...)

Comment: Also, GCC is making pretty inefficient code for those 2 byte loads, I think.  It looks like `movzwl 0x80(%rsp), %eax` / `shl $8, %eax` would work.  Do you have source that can reproduce that missed optimization?  Or does that only happen with some old GCC version?

Comment: I really not sure, but maybe it because some relaxations. I mean imagine an architecture which has a `JUMP` instruction which can only jump to `256` byte away. And you call a `foo` fuction which is in this range so something like `JUMP foo` will generated. Now this might valid in that compilation unit, but when you link it with other codes `foo` might get out of that `256` byte range so it be must replaced by a similar instruction which is able to make that longer jump. So it is not necessary an optimization it might could be just necessary to make the code valid.

Comment: Please make an [mcve] including the exact compiler versions and the exact commands you type to generate the faulty binary.  There are multiple possible issues and without knowing at least how exactly compiler and linker are invoced, it is hard to say what the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks to all helpful comments.  I find the problem. Please see the answer posted by myself.  Please don't upvote. Sorry for ask a incomplete and silly question.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the comments. I have found the problem, as Peter Cordes said in the comment, I linked to another set of sqlite library. I installed too many sets of GCC compiler environment, and each compiler has its own sqlite in its default library path. My project was managed by cmake, it remembered all previous GCC settings...

Steps to discover:

1. add -v flag to gcc commands.
2. copy the ld commands out, and add flag "--print-map -Map=demo.map", run the full ld command again.
3. search the library name (sqlite here) in demo.map, I clearly find another set of sqlite library has been linked. Realise how stupid I am...

Update: I have a new problem: if the library.a is compiled with an advanced CPU instruction, how to downgrade it in link stage, seems those instructions will be copied into binary without checking the -march flags in GCC.

Comment: Supplying `library.a` is pretty much like supplying a bunch of loose `.o` files.  If they were compiled with `-mbmi`, you can't link them into an executable that might run on earlier CPUs.  Linking with `gcc -march=whatever` doesn't filter linker inputs, and in fact object files don't even have metadata to record required-ISA-extensions.  (Although that would allow automated checking like you're wishing for, interesting idea...)